# Canon AE-1 mirror stuck but can wind film and take photos

Tags: canon, film, troubleshooting, 35mm, mirror

My Canon AE-1 camera's mirror is getting stuck in the up position after taking a photo. I can wind the film with the lever and the mirror goes back down but once I take a photo, the mirror stays in the up position. Does anyone know how to fix this? I also just put in a brand new battery so that is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a mechanical issue, and like the mirror is getting locked. You might need to replace the mirror bumper. I would suggest getting it professionally serviced.

Is your film still winding after the mirror gets stuck? If not, there might be something (a piece of plastic for example) that has broken off and gotten stuck in the winding mechanism.

Hope this helps!